# My question was locked as off topic. Where should I take it to

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

I made a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/458993/what-are-the-data-link-protocols-for-cellular-networks), and I was starting to get some good information on it, but it wwas closed as off topic without even a recommendation of where to take it.

This is not a trivial question every IT pro should know the answer to, but if there is anywhere where there's a chance of having people who know the answer is here.

Also, how can I ask the close voters to give me feedback when closing my question? I don't think I'm being deliberately trying to ask a blatantly off topic question, or acting maliciously or in bad faith, but getting my question closed is not very constructive, and doesn't help the question solved.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking your question is On-Topic for Server Fault. I have re-opened it. The rehtorical answer as to why is was closed is that 5 High Reputation users though it should be, and felt the closing didn't require explanation. There is some confusion with telephone, cellular, and other PSTN questions in our community...

Lots of history condensed into three sentences: Server Fault was originally the one Trilogy site for all Professional Computer/Technical Administration questions (SO being development, and SU being non-Professional administration and general use). Then Area51 splintered Stack Exchange into 50+ different topics/sites, many of which stole topicality from the original Trilogy sites. One of those the was a Telecommunications site, which is now defunct, and got mostly merged back into SF.

Server Fault is now the correct site for all Professionally managed Data Transit services (so long as you meet the normal minimum requirements: administrative privileged, baseline knowledge, reasonable effort).

Comment: I'm glad to see it reopened. This question got shut as OT on Stack overflow & generated a meta thread there, so I invited the OP here to post it again, and I was surprised to see it closed here.

Answer (score 4):

The question was closed by 5 high-rep users on the site. It's unfortunate that none of them felt the need to leave a message as to why. Especially considering it has a +5 score, which is pretty good for this site.

Anyhow I see it's been re-opened by Chris now. You've done the right thing by bringing it to us on meta.

Answer (score 1):

I've just cast a close vote on that question (since it's been reopened). I tossed up whether to cast it for `Not Constructive` or `Not a Real Question` and went with the former. It's not a question appropriate to a Q&A site like SF. Nor is it on a topic that the very vast majority of us would consider part of working as an IT professional (within the scope defined in the FAQ). It's a *good* question certainly, which I'm sure is why it received the upvotes, but it's not a good fit for SF.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Where do you think I could take it to?

Comment: I really don't know. There was a proposal for a Stack Exchange site devoted to telephony recently but, oddly enough, it got killed off as a duplicate of SF (which it certainly wasn't). I believe your question would have been a great fit there.

Comment: Just a small side question: Do you think the question is not appropriate because of the definition of this site? (impartially applying the rules) or because you think it is not in the general spirit of this site.

Comment: A bit of both really. The way I see it there are two key points. 1- It's not a question that requires an answer that is much more involved than what we normally have (although there are some legendary exceptions). 2 - It's a topic that doesn't really fit the SF profile. i.e. It's not about the topics covered by what we define as an IT professional. That definition is pretty important because without it SF would become as sloppy and ill-defined as Stack Overflow, which would make it pretty well worthless for those it was intended for.

Comment: Well, actually, this is not in my opinion a telephony question, but a programming one. The ultimate question is actually "how can I improve communications performance for smartphone applications over 3G?", but not only that's an incredibly broad question, but also too much "do my homework". So I thought that a good starting point would be to learn more about the 3G network stack, and asked this question at SO, where it got closed. So I came here. I think SF is not only the most likely place to get an answer, but also where people interested in this question are. (reflected by the upvotes)